# React Native, the ActivityIndicator is not shown because data inside Flatlist are rendered too quickly, but not enough

Tags: javascript, react-native, activity-indicator, flatlist

I'm new with React Native and I'm trying to display a very long flatlist.

More specifically there are two arrays (a movies one and a tvs one). When I tap a specific switch I want to swap the array. So in order to make the app render the items faster while swapping "category" I've decided to use the **onEndReached** props and render 10 items at a time.

I'm fetching the whole two arrays during the **componentDidMount** method.

Now when I reach the end of the list and the 10 more items are being displayed I also want to show an **ActivityIndicator**.

My problem is that when I set my **loading** state to true and I add the other items to the **displyedProducts** array, then I set back again to false the loading state in order to hide the indicator, my indicator is never shown because the **loading** state changes too quickly although there's a full second to wait before the new elements are rendered while using the app.

Here there is the specific code block which load new items:

```
loadMore = () => {
    const {
      displayedProducts,
      products,
      tvs,
      movies,
      searchedMovies,
      isSearching,
    } = this.state;
    const tempArray = displayedProducts;

    if (
      (products === 'movies' && tempArray.length === movies.length) ||
      (products === 'tvs' && tempArray.length === tvs.length) ||
      (isSearching && tempArray.length === searchedMovies.length)
    ) {
      return;
    }

    this.setState({loading: true}, () => {
      products === 'movies' &&
        tempArray.push(
          ...movies.slice(tempArray.length, tempArray.length + 10),
        );

      products === 'tvs' &&
        tempArray.push(...tvs.slice(tempArray.length, tempArray.length + 10));

      this.setState({displayedProducts: tempArray}, () => {
        this.state.loading && this.setState({loading: false});
      });
    });
};
```

I've also tried to set to false the **loading** state in the **componentDidUpdate** method but nothing changed.
Do you guys know how can I solve this problem?

I'll leave here the whole component code:

```
import React from 'react';
import {
  SafeAreaView,
  FlatList,
  StatusBar,
  StyleSheet,
  View,
  ActivityIndicator,
} from 'react-native';
import {sortBy} from 'lodash';
import {getMovies, getTvs} from '../Services/MovieManager';
import Header from '../components/Header';
import MovieCard from '../components/MovieCard';
import NavigationSwitch from '../components/NavigationSwitch';

class HomeView extends React.PureComponent {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);

    this.state = {
      movies: [],
      tvs: [],
      displayedProducts: [],
      searchedMovies: [],
      products: 'movies',
      isSearching: false,
      loading: false,
    };

    this.flatListRef = React.createRef(null);
  }

  componentDidMount() {
    this.fetchProducts();
  }

  fetchProducts = () => {
    getMovies()
      .then(movies => {
        const moviesList = sortBy(movies.items, movie => movie.title);
        this.setState({
          movies: moviesList,
          displayedProducts: moviesList.slice(0, 10),
        });
      })
      .then(
        getTvs().then(tvs => {
          const tvsList = sortBy(tvs.items, tv => tv.title);
          this.setState({tvs: tvsList});
        }),
      );
  };

  navigate = item => () => {
    this.props.navigation.navigate('Movie', {movie: item});
  };

  renderItem = ({item}) => (
    <MovieCard movie={item} onPress={this.navigate(item)} />
  );

  ItemSeparator = () => <View style={styles.itemSeparator} />;

  getSearchedResults = searchedString => {
    const {products, movies, tvs} = this.state;
    let tempProducts = [];
    const regEx = new RegExp(`\\b${searchedString.toLowerCase()}`);

    searchedString
      ? this.setState({isSearching: true})
      : this.setState({isSearching: false});

    ((products === 'movies' && movies) || (products === 'tvs' && tvs)).forEach(
      product => {
        product.title.toLowerCase().match(regEx) && tempProducts.push(product);
      },
    );

    this.setState({
      searchedMovies: tempProducts,
      displayedProducts: tempProducts.slice(0, 10),
    });

    this.flatListRef.scrollToOffset({animated: true, offset: 0});
  };

  setList = result => {
    const {movies, tvs} = this.state;

    this.setState({
      products: result,
      displayedProducts: (
        (result === 'movies' && movies) ||
        (result === 'tvs' && tvs)
      ).slice(0, 10),
    });

    this.flatListRef.scrollToOffset({animated: true, offset: 0});
  };

  loadMore = () => {
    const {
      displayedProducts,
      products,
      tvs,
      movies,
      searchedMovies,
      isSearching,
    } = this.state;
    const tempArray = displayedProducts;

    if (
      (products === 'movies' && tempArray.length === movies.length) ||
      (products === 'tvs' && tempArray.length === tvs.length) ||
      (isSearching && tempArray.length === searchedMovies.length)
    ) {
      return;
    }

    this.setState({loading: true}, () => {
      products === 'movies' &&
        tempArray.push(
          ...movies.slice(tempArray.length, tempArray.length + 10),
        );

      products === 'tvs' &&
        tempArray.push(...tvs.slice(tempArray.length, tempArray.length + 10));

      this.setState({displayedProducts: tempArray}, () => {
        this.state.loading && this.setState({loading: false});
      });
    });
  };

  render() {
    const {displayedProducts, loading} = this.state;

    return (
      <>
        <StatusBar barStyle="dark-content" backgroundColor="white" />

        <Header
          title="Home"
          getSearchedResults={search => {
            this.getSearchedResults(search);
          }}
          style={styles.header}
        />
        <View style={styles.mainContent}>
          <NavigationSwitch setList={this.setList} />

          <SafeAreaView>
            <FlatList
              ref={ref => (this.flatListRef = ref)}
              data={displayedProducts}
              numColumns={2}
              keyExtractor={item => item.id}
              renderItem={this.renderItem}
              columnWrapperStyle={{justifyContent: 'space-around'}}
              ItemSeparatorComponent={this.ItemSeparator}
              contentContainerStyle={styles.flatList}
              initialNumToRender={10}
              maxToRenderPerBatch={10}
              onEndReached={this.loadMore}
            />
          </SafeAreaView>

          {loading && <ActivityIndicator style={styles.indicator} />}
        </View>
      </>
    );
  }
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  mainContent: {
    elevation: 2,
    height: '100%',
    zIndex: -1,
    elevation: -1,
  },
  flatList: {
    paddingVertical: 80,
    zIndex: -1,
  },
  itemSeparator: {
    height: 25,
    width: '100%',
  },
  indicator: {
    flex: 1,
    alignSelf: 'center',
    bottom: 100,
    elevation: 4,
  },
});

export default HomeView;
```